# Why don't institutions share stock recommendations like Wall Street analysts?

Tags: stock-analysis, recommendation

The article [Track Institutional Buying, Not Analysts](http://education.investors.com/investors-corner/419239-track-institutional-buying-not-analysts.htm) states that:

> Mutual funds, insurance companies, pension funds and other
>   institutional investors rely on their own research. Contrary to
>   analysts who publish their recommendations, institutions keep opinions
>   to themselves. They're also reluctant to give any hint of what they're
>   trading

Why is this so? Institutions have the same reason to recommend the stocks they are buying, to drive its price up. What good do they achieve by keeping the info secret?

Comment: Why on earth would an institution like a mutual fund want to drive up the price of stock that _it_ is _contemplating_ buying before it has actually purchased the shares? Does the institution _want_ to pay higher prices? Far better to drive up the price of stock _after_ making the purchase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primarily because they don't want big price movements when they are in the market. If they spook the markets, either they have to buy at a higher price, or they sell at a lower price or they decrease the price of their holdings(which isn't always a big factor). The 3 situations they didn't want to be in the first place.

And the most important thing is most analysts are dumb bozos, whom you should ignore. They tout because they want to increase their exposure in your eyes, so that they may land a job in one of those big investment companies, or they might be holding stocks and want to profit from it. Frankly speaking if you take advice from the so called analysts, be prepared to say goodbye to your money some day, mayn't be always. One near case maybe Carson Block from Muddy Waters, but he does his homework properly.

Answer (score 4):

Institutions may be buying large quantities of the stock and would want the price to go up after they are done buying all that they have to buy.  If the price jumps before they finish buying then they may not make as great a deal as they would otherwise.  Consider buying tens of thousands of shares of a company and then how does one promote that?  Also, what kind of PR system should those investment companies have to disclose whether or not they have holdings in these companies.  This is just some of the stuff you may be missing here.

The "Wall street analysts" are the investment banks that want the companies to do business through them and thus it is a win/win relationship as the bank gets some fees for all the transactions done for the company while the company gets another cheerleader to try to play up the stock.